Is there a rule for the "Not so easy is it now" expression?
I've heard the expression:

Not so easy is it now, boy!

I got it said - in a way that didn't sound like a question, though. It's odd to me because the order of words is reversed ("is it").
Is there a rule behind the expression? Or is it just a set phrase?
